# Best way to manage the persistence of a form state, to and from a database

Tags: forms, jsp, save, criteria, restore

In a JSP/Servlet webapp, I have to implement a functionality that allows a user to save or restore a form state, that latter containing for instance some search criteria.

In other words, the user must be able to save or restore field values of a form, at any time. On the same page that contains that form, there's also another little form that allows him to name his form state before saving it. Then, later he'll be able to recall that state, via a combobox, and refill dynamically the form with the state he selected.

I know how to implement that by hand but I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel then I'd like to know if there are some frameworks managing that kind of functionality ? A mix between JSP taglib, filter class, jQuery or other JavaScript frameworks...

My research has not give anything yet.

Thank you in advance.